# SQL Server not use all the available memory after server memory upgrade

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

We have an old Windows 2008 server with SQL Server 2005, it has 16GB DDR3 RAM and SQL Server uses up to 14G from it, and write almost the same amount to the page file, so we decide to upgrade.

After we install the 64GB ram to the server, everything seems working except the SQL Server still using 14GB, regardless how much free physical memory remaining.

We have set the SQL Server instance property max memory to 60GB already, set the page lock in group policy, still, the maximum usage stays at 14GB

We also did a query in SQL Server with `sys.dm_os_performance_counters`, the target memory for SQL Server is 56GB, total server memory is at 14GB. According to the MS document, seems our server is under huge memory pressure.

Are we missing settings? or can someone point us where to look for to solve the issue? Thanks